# OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot start the driver service on localhost using Selenium WebDriver with C# performing Unit Test

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit, teardown

I'm learning `Selenium/Webdriver` `NUnit` testing and run into a problem when executing a test:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using NUnit.Framework;

class NUnitTest
{
    IWebDriver driver;
    FirefoxOptions options;

   [SetUp]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    [Test]
    public void OpenAppTest()
    {
       driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http:/www.demoqa.com");
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void EndTEst()
    {
        driver.Quit();
    }
}
```

When running test, I'm getting an exception:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot start the driver service on
>   localhost TearDown: System.NUllReferenceException: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object

I have no clue how to fix it.

However, the following approach works:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;    
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

public class UnitTest1
{
    IWebDriver driver;
    [TestMethod]
    public void VerifyTitle()
    {
        //Write Actual Test
        string title = driver.Title;
        Assert.AreEqual(title, "Demoqa | Just another WordPress site");
    }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        //start browser and open url
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http:/www.demoqa.com");
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void CleanupTest()
    {
        //close browser
        driver.Quit();
    }
}
```

Here, I'm using the same approach to start the `webdriver` as in the failing example.
The only difference is that the failing example is using `NUnit.Framework` and the correct one is using `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`

I'm not sure what is wrong with the second approach?

Comment: I would recommend editing your title to make it clear that your problem is with WebDriver and "NUnit" specifically. I am curious why it works through a MS unit test but not with NUnit.

Comment: What version of the .NET bindings are you using? What version of Firefox? From your description, it sounds like you're using version 3.0.0 of Selenium, and a recent version of Firefox.(version >= 48). If so, you need the [geckodriver executable](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) to go along with your project.

Comment: I had similar issues with NUnit and it was because the actual exe that runs the tests is not in the same directory as your project's bin output. I used: driver = new FirefoxDriver(FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService("path to driver directory"));